# Question on partial fractions; why numerator has to be one lower degree than denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

When decomposing into a partial fraction, why does the highest degree of the numerator have to be one lower than the numerator?

For example:

$\frac{x}{x^3-1} = \frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{bx+c}{x^2+x+1}$

and not:

$\frac{x}{x^3-1} = \frac{a}{x-1} + \frac{b}{x^2+x+1}$

Comment: Who claimed that? It *doesn't* have to be like that.

Comment: In your example, there would be no way to get rid of $x^2$ term otherwise

Comment: In the case $\frac{2x^2+x}{x^3-1}$ for example , the second approach would give $a=2$ , $a+b=1$ , $a-b=0$ , which has no solution.

Comment: From the theoretical standpoint, all we know about decomposition is that degree of numerator is less than degree of the denominator so we have to assume that it can be a polynomial of degree 1 if denominator is quadratic. Similarly, if denominator is cubic (root multiplicity of three), we have to assume that numerator can be quadratic.

Comment: Try it, in your second expression you will find that $b$ depends on $x$ i.e you will find different values of $b$ depending on which $x$ you use to find it.